# Angularjs file upload doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4, angularjs-directive

Hi i'm trying to upload a file using danialfarid library.

https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

However when I ask the server if it received a file, I keep getting false back.

Here is the upload function in my controller:

```
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {

      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'menu/update', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
        method: 'PUT',
        //headers: {'header-key': 'header-value'},
        //withCredentials: true,
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: $files[i], 


      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      });
      //.error(...)
      //.then(success, error, progress); 
      // access or attach event listeners to the underlying XMLHttpRequest.
      //.xhr(function(xhr){xhr.upload.addEventListener(...)})
    }
    /* alternative way of uploading, send the file binary with the file's content-type.
       Could be used to upload files to CouchDB, imgur, etc... html5 FileReader is needed. 
       It could also be used to monitor the progress of a normal http post/put request with large data*/
    // $scope.upload = $upload.http({...})  see 88#issuecomment-31366487 for sample code.
  };
```

Here is the request payload from chrome console I'm sending:

```
--WebKitFormBoundaryozbcZE1o6Nnkd2F7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myObj"

undefined
------WebKitFormBoundaryozbcZE1o6Nnkd2F7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="avatar-mini4.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryozbcZE1o6Nnkd2F7--
```

My server code in laravel

```
public function upload(){
        Input::hasFile('file')
            return Response::json(array(    $file), 200
                );  
}
```

Comment: So then it's the Laravel side that has the problem? Why not dump $_FILES on the server and see what the contents are? I usually do AngularJS uploads with no 3rd party libs, I could show you but that's another story :)

Comment: I dumped the files and it says null. Which makes me think it's the angularjs side?

Comment: Odd, because I thought Chrome was showing that the file was sending. Still not solved? So that I take said library for a spin and help you. Also, has the library ever worked for you before? I saw a similar question about that library, which also has no answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975491/angularjs-uploader-server-side-with-php?rq=1

Comment: Thanks i would appreciate that.  I used the library last year but it updated with the release of angularjsjs v.1.2